# Can software developed on 64-bit Windows 7 run on 32bit OS (Windows XP or Windows 7)? 

Tags: c#, .net

I want to update my work computer from 32-bit Windows XP to 64bit Windows 7, but I am worried that the software develop in 64-bit Windows 7 can not work on 32bit OS, just like Windows XP and Windows 7.

Comment: you can build software for anycpu or target specific platform - x64 or x86.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works without problems. You just need to make sure you compile your binaries with the platform target "Any CPU".

However, be aware of the following:

1. When you are using unmanaged DLLs, you must provide them in a 32 bit version for the 32 bit systems and in a 64 bit version for the 64 bit systems.
   If you only have 32 bit versions of your unmanaged DLLs you can also choose "x86" as the platform target. Your application will than run as a 32 bit process even on 64 bit systems.
2. When you are using Windows 7 features in your application, it will most likely not run correctly on Windows XP.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that you can explicitly compile for x86 as well - useful if your unmanaged DLLs are only 32-bit, then you won't get a nasty surprise when your code is run on a 64 bit machine.